# Why do i have to re-declare properties in typescript angular controller functions

Tags: angularjs, typescript

```
export interface IFooModel {
    foo:string;
    fooFunction(fooProp:string):void;
}

 export class FooCtrl implements IFooModel {
    constructor(public foo:string){
    }

    fooFunction(fooProp:string):void{
    }
}
```

The code above is fairly standard. My question is , when i want to access `foo:string` in the function i have to do this

```
fooFunction(fooProp:string):void{
   var fooAgain = this.foo;

  // Pretend i set it up properly for $mdDialog to work
  this.$mdDialog.show(options).then(function(answer: boolean) {
       if (answer) {
             // fooAgain works
             // this.foo does not work 
       }
}
```

Why do i have to set `this.foo` to a variable in order to access it inside another function , instead of just writing `this.foo` ? In some functions i end up for about 4 variables declarations that are already declared in the constructor. Is there maybe a better way to this? I get the feels that there is too much repeat code in the controller.

Comment: Are you trying to declare a function inside a Method?

Comment: i updated my question , hopefully it makes more sense , i was going down a foo rabbit hole there

Comment: Ah yes I understand now, `this` is a know problem in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a problem in Javascript, but thankfully in TypeScript this problem is no more thanks to fat arrows! Yay!

Fat arrows are like anonymous functions but handle the `this` variable for you. 
Let me show you:

```
fooFunction(fooProp:string):void {
    // Pretend i set it up properly for $mdDialog to work
    this.$mdDialog.show(options).then((answer: boolean) => {
        if (answer) {
            this.foo = "";  
        }
     });
}
```

Using fat arrows this will now compile to this in JS:

```
FooCtrl.prototype.fooFunction = function (fooProp) {
    var _this = this;
    // Pretend i set it up properly for $mdDialog to work
    this.$mdDialog.show(options).then(function (answer) {
        if (answer) {
            _this.foo = "";
        }
    });
};
```

So Typescript automatically creates a `_this` variable for you, so that you no longer have the problem. Pretty neat if you ask me.

Here's the documentation for Arrow functions: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I know SO says we must refrain from saying thanks .. but .. thanks

Comment: Absolutely no problem! These things are frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to place the value in a local variable prior to calling a function is because you expect the class to go out of scope (i.e. something will happen to change the scope, such as a callback or asynchronous operation).

By putting the value in a local variable it becomes part of the closure for the function and the value is stored alongside the function itself.

This is one of the trickiest aspects of JavaScript - scope is kinda funky.

There are other options to solve this problem, including fat arrows...

```
() => {
    // this.foo is now preserved
}
```

Or `call` / `apply` which allow you to set the scope.

Comment: I know SO says we must refrain from saying thanks .. but .. thanks